# Do PHP $_SESSIONS work on included pages?

Tags: php, session

Let's say I have header.tpl and footer.tpl and in-between those two goes body.tpl.

Let's say I want to restrict access to body.tpl by checking whether a specific session is set something like:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['limited'])) {
  //render body.tpl
} else {
  //direct somewhere else
}
```

Would this work if the `session_start(); if (isset()) {` part is located in the header.tpl and the `} else {}` is located in the footer.tpl file?

My plan is that I do the session checking in the header and footer which get included into every page, so I wouldn't have to do that in the PHP files that render the templates.

Like this(contents of body.tpl):

```
<?php require_once(TEMPLATE_PATH. "/header.tpl"); ?>
//body.tpl contents
<?php require_once(TEMPLATE_PATH. "/footer.tpl"); ?>
```

The body.tpl gets called via a PHP file that `requires` all the necessary files and instantiates all the classes that will be used to fill out the tpl file. If I do session checking in the PHP file it works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the $_SESSION object from any PHP code while executing a request. Make sure you call session_start only once.

ps. this approach brings code duplication and you will regret it.

Answer (score 0):

You an do better if you use a template engine (try http://www.smarty.net/)

You will be able to do this and much more with a lot of ease. You will be able to do something along these lines.

Assume you want to show a page foo.tpl, an you have two other smarty templates
1. header.tpl
2. footer.tpl

foo.tpl will look something like this

```
{include file="header.tpl"}

{$foo}

{include file="footer.tpl"}
```

then in your php page, do whatever logic you want, load the output into an variable via

```
$smarty-assign('foo',$my_content);
$smarty->display( "foo.tpl" );
```

this would render foo.tpl, include the content of header.tpl and footer.tpl along with $foo